# How to Display top 5 landing pages from google search console to data studio?

Tags: data-visualization, data-analysis, dashboard, looker-studio, google-search-console

I want to modify a table so that it can show only top 5 landing pages from search console on data studio? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have already added GSC as the data source.

*In the table settings, on the Data Tab*
Landing Page for Dimension and URL Clicks as the Metric.
Rows per Page set to 5.
Sort by URL Clicks in either ascending or descending order.

*On the Style Tab*
Under Table Footer settings, uncheck pagination.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, sorry for late reply. i will keep your suggestion in mind